# Installed a Grails distribution from source which is missing profiles

Tags: grails, installation

I want to install and use my own patched Grails distribution. 
I am reading the steps from the [documentation](http://docs.grails.org/latest/guide/single.html#build)

The steps I have done so far:

1. Checked out the source code `git clone git@github.com:grails/grails-core.git`
2. Changed to release branch `git checkout 3.3.x`
3. Built the project `./gradlew install`
4. Add it to SDKMAN `sdk install grails dev .`
5. Use the new Grails distribution `sdk use grails dev`

So far good, running `grails -version` has following output

```
| Grails Version: 3.3.10.BUILD-SNAPSHOT
| JVM Version: 1.8.0_191
```

But when I create a new Grails application I get the following error:

```
$ grails create-app newtestapp
| Error Error occurred running Grails CLI: Could not find artifact org.grails.profiles:web:jar: in grailsCentral (https://repo.grails.org/grails/core) (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
```

Which seems to be related missing profiles:

```
$ grails list-profiles
| Available Profiles
--------------------
```

How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 2):

You have to checkout and run `./gradlew pTML` for the profile you want to use from https://github.com/grails-profiles